# Google Analytics and Internet Explorer 8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I know there are news about

> Google dropping support of Google Analytics for Internet Explorer 8 by end of the year

or has already dropped.

But what if I want to continue using Google Analytics for my website and give compatibility in IE 8 too.

Has anyone has a way to work around it???

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

["As a note, we’ll of course continue to measure traffic from IE8 browsers to your website."](http://analytics.blogspot.de/2013/09/supporting-modern-browsing-experience.html)

You won't be able to use the admin interface with IE8 (no way around that), but that should harldy be a problem. Data will still be collected from IE8 (and previous).